# Handling endless data stream with multiprocessing and Queues

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I want to use the Python 2.7 multiprocessing package to operate on an endless stream of data.  A subprocess will constantly receive data via TCP/IP or UDP packets and immediately place the data in a multiprocessing.Queue.  However, at certain intervals, say, every 500ms, I only want to operate on a user specified slice of this data.  Let's say, the last 200 data packets.

I know I can put() and get() on the Queue, but how can I create that slice of data without a) Backing up the queue and b) Keeping things threadsafe?

I'm thinking I have to constantly get() from the Queue with another subprocess to prevent the Queue from getting full.  Then I have to store the data in another data structure (such as a list) to build the user specified slice.  But the data structure would probably not be thread safe, so it does not sound like a good solution.

Is there some programming paradigm that achieves what I am trying to do easily?  I looked at the multiprocessing.Manager class, but wasn't sure it would work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the forums for asking a question before posting. Show what you have tried and what is not working, please provide code. Avoid broad opinion-based queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

- Use an instance of the `threading.Lock` class. Call method `acquire` to claim exclusive access to your queue from a certain thread and call `release` to grant other threads access.
- Since you want to keep gathering your input, copying the whole queue would be probably be to expensive. Probably the fastest way is to first collect data in one queue, than swap it for another and use the old one to read data from into your application by a different thread. Protect the swapping with a Lock instance, so you can be sure that whenever the writer acquires the lock, the current 'listener' queue is ready to receive data.
- If only recent data is important, use two circular buffer instead of queues, allowing old data to be overwritten.